# Efficient ActiveRecord association conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

Let's say you have an assocation in one of your models like this:

```
class User
  has_many :articles
end
```

Now assume you need to get 3 arrays, one for the articles written yesterday, one of for the articles written in the last 7 days, and one of for the articles written in the last 30 days.

Of course you might do this:

```
articles_yesterday = user.articles.where("posted_at >= ?", Date.yesterday)
articles_last7d    = user.articles.where("posted_at >= ?", 7.days.ago.to_date)
articles_last30d   = user.articles.where("posted_at >= ?", 30.days.ago.to_date)
```

However, this will run 3 separate database queries. More efficiently, you could do this:

```
articles_last30d   = user.articles.where("posted_at >= ?", 30.days.ago.to_date)
articles_yesterday = articles_last30d.select { |article| 
  article.posted_at >= Date.yesterday 
}
articles_last7d    = articles_last30d.select { |article| 
  article.posted_at >= 7.days.ago.to_date
}
```

Now of course this is a contrived example and there is no guarantee that the array select will actually be faster than a database query, but let's just assume that it is.

My question is: Is there any way (e.g. some gem) to write this code in a way which eliminates this problem by making sure that you simply specify the association conditions, and the application itself will decide whether it needs to perform another database query or not?

ActiveRecord itself does not seem to cover this problem appropriately. You are forced to decide between querying the database every time or treating the association as an array.

Comment: What do you want to get rid of? The extra array, the extra queries, or just the typing?

Comment: In my actual code I'm usually not aware of whether or not some association is already loaded. I want to write code which doesn't need to care about this, and still always makes the minimum number of database queries.

Comment: I don't think that there is any out of the box solution for this. It would require a great effort to keep track of all the conditions and loaded data. Not to talk about the fact that database can change behind the scene. You manually need to create optimal queries. For that, you can use tricks to make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle this:

You can create separate associations for each level that you want by specifying a conditions hash on the association definition.  Then you can simply eager load these associations for your User query, and you will be hitting the db 3x for the entire operation instead of 3x for each user.

```
class User
  has_many articles_yesterday, class_name: Article, conditions: ['posted_at >= ?', Date.yesterday]
   # other associations the same way
end

User.where(...).includes(:articles_yesterday, :articles_7days, :articles_30days)
```

You could do a group by.

What it comes down to is you need to profile your code and determine what's going to be fastest for your app (or if you should even bother with it at all)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not enough. I'm already eager loading wherever possible, and in this scenario it would be necessary to eager load only one association, not three, because it's a performance-critical application.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the necessity of checking the query with something like the code below.

```
class User
  has_many :articles

  def article_30d
    @articles_last30d ||= user.articles.where("posted_at >= ?", 30.days.ago.to_date)
  end

  def articles_last7d 
    @articles_last7d ||= articles_last30d.select { |article| article.posted_at >= 7.days.ago.to_date }
  end

  def articles_yesterday 
    @articles_yesterday ||= articles_last30d.select { |article| article.posted_at >= Date.yesterday }
  end

end
```

What it does:

- Makes only one query maximum, if any of the three is used
- Calculates only the used array, and the 30d version in any case, but only once

It does not however simplifies the initial 30d query even if you do not use it. Is it enough, or you need something more?

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing at the moment, my example above is just a simplication.